# UITextView value not converting to string

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am having trouble getting a .text value from a `UITextView` to convert to a string so I can index it and spit the string on "\n".  If I pass a string in quotes it works but if I use the .text value it refuses split on the "\n"

Here is my function:

```
func formatLabel(string: String, title_color: UIColor, title_font_size: CGFloat, title_font_weight: UIFont.Weight, subtitle_color: UIColor, subtitle_font_size: CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    //getting the range to separate the button title strings
    let index = string.index(of: "\n") ?? string.endIndex
    let substring1 = String(string[..<index])
    let substring2 = String(string[index...])

    print("string:", string)
    print("index: ",index)
    print("line 1", substring1)
    print("line 2", substring2)

}
```

here is my ViewController code:

```
    @IBAction func btnUpdate(_ sender: Any) {
        txtOutput.attributedText = formatLabel(string: txtInput.text!, title_color: UIColor.gray, title_font_size: 17, title_font_weight: UIFont.Weight.bold, subtitle_color: UIColor.lightGray, subtitle_font_size: 13)
        txtOutput2.attributedText = formatLabel(string: "Title\nSub Title", title_color: UIColor.gray, title_font_size: 17, title_font_weight: UIFont.Weight.bold, subtitle_color: UIColor.lightGray, subtitle_font_size: 13)
    }
```

Here is the print output:

```
string: Title\nSub Title  
index:  Index(_compoundOffset: 64, _cache:    
Swift.String.Index._Cache.utf16)  
line 1 Title\nSub Title  
line 2  
string: Title   
Sub Title  
index:  Index(_compoundOffset: 20, _cache:   Swift.String.Index._Cache.character(1))   
line 1 Title  
line 2  
Sub Title
```

So, I can not get the line to break on the index(of: "\n") when using a UITextView control but just fine when I use a literal text.  All I can figure is in Swift 4 there is something funky that has to be done to deal the CompoundOffset.  That's poorly documented so can't figure out how to solve my issue and have the control text behave as a string.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First post... sorry.  Tightened it up.

Comment: From your output, it looks like your `UITextView` contains a backslash followed by an `n` which is not the same as `"\n"` which is a single newline character.

Comment: Do not actually type in the character \ followed by an `n` while typing in the text view. Tap the Enter key on keyboard to enter a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITextView` component does not automatically translate the "\n" typed by the user into a return character.

You could use:

```
txtOutput.attributedText = formatLabel(string: txtInput.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n"), title_color: UIColor.gray, title_font_size: 17, title_font_weight: UIFont.Weight.bold, subtitle_color: UIColor.lightGray, subtitle_font_size: 13)
```

This will replace the "\n" with a proper return character.

p.s. You shouldn't force-unwrap the `txtInput.text` value, however.

Comment: This worked.  Since I have a common function I adapted and move the replace over to my function so it's more agnostic in terms of source of the string and how that source handles it.  

`let string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")`